# Помогите советом как можно заблокировать открытый порт из Java-программы

Tags: java

Добрый день. Подскажите, как можно заблокировать порт  из Java-программы, если он открыт у меня на компьютере. Дело в том, что открыт он программой, которую я не могу закрыть(управляется централизованной политикой), хоть я и имею права локального админа на данной рабочей станции Windows.Штатный файерволл Windows выключен политикой контроллера домена, так что им я тоже не могу ограничить эту программу. Остается лишь написать мини-программку которая будет сидеть и блочить соединение на данный 14000 порт. Но как это сделать-не знаю. Опыта работы с сетью нет.

Comment: Никак. Одна программа не может блокировать порт другой программы.

Comment: Если порт просто открыт и ни кем не используется. Тогда вы можете занять его (тем самым закрыв для других)

Comment: Сергей, ну брандмауэр WIndows же как то блокирует) точнее даже сказать - он не дает пакетам с данного порта выходить за пределы компьютера, а также дропает приходящие на этот порт пакеты.

Comment: Александр, а если порт открыт другой программой, то как мы можем его занять? Система не даст нам открыть сокет с данным номером порта

Comment: под юниксом есть утилита tpckill под windows аналог wKillcx.  исходники: http://wkillcx.sourceforge.net

мысль: по таймеру вызывать скрипт закрытия порта

Comment: Алексей, вы имеете ввиду из java-кода вызывать что-то типа  Runtime.exec(wkill script)? А какой будет триггер для таймера ?

Comment: Можно попробывать запустить вашу программу раньше, чем запускается та, которая использует порт, дабы заблокировать своей программой порт. Если неугодная программа сервис, то напишите сервис и обеспечьте запуск раньше.

Comment: Но скорее всего вам понадобится для этого более низкоуровневый язык (С/С++)

Comment: ActivX, спасибо за ответ. Подскажите, чтоб использовать C/C++ , это придется как-то подключать классы C++ из кода Java? (я новичок в Java, так что прошу прощения  за глупый вопрос)